# Struggling with simple orthographic projection for a 2D setup

Tags: c#, directx11, sharpdx

I'm trying to build a simple setup for 2D using SharpDX. Basically I want to supply my vertices in classic Cartesian coordinates: X-right, Y-up, starting with (0,0) in bottom-left corner. I've had similar experience with PSM (Sony OpenGL ES based framework for PS Vita and mobile), so I've used similar approach. The main work here is basically to construct a MVP transformation. Basic verification math on paper (800x600 screen):

[image]

so everything seems right here. So our target mvp matrix should match `refT`. The supplied point (50, 200) maps to (-0.875, -0.333) in clip space.

I used [SharpDX-Samples\Desktop\Direct3D11\MiniCube](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D11/MiniCube) as a starting point. I've modified it to leave a single cube plane, added texturing, everithing working fine so far. Then I replaced original coordinates with pixel-based one, and changed MVP calculation to this:

```
var model = Matrix.Identity;
var view = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0, 0, -1), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitY);
var proj = Matrix.OrthoOffCenterLH(0, form.ClientSize.Width, 0, form.ClientSize.Height, 0, 1);
var worldViewProj = model * (view * proj);
context.UpdateSubresource(ref worldViewProj, constantBuffer);
```

The `worldViewProj` is exactly as expected with math above. However there is nothing on the screen. I feel like I very close to solution but missing something. Any suggestions appreciated.

Complete [main file gist](https://gist.github.com/pabdulin/d5103312cda19322dfa4). The part with `ORTHO` undefined is original sample code and it's working properly. With `ORTHO` defined is my new "pixel coordinates" approach which is not working as expected.

**Update 1**: as David suggested I've tried following modification:

```
var rDesc = RasterizerStateDescription.Default();
rDesc.CullMode = CullMode.None; // also tried CullMode.Front and CullMode.Back
var rState = new RasterizerState(device, rDesc);
context.Rasterizer.State = rState;
```

but it didn't seem to help in any way. I've also rearranged vertex order to be exactly in same order as in sample, but also with no success.

Comment: Have you checked back-face culling? Some projection matrices end up with a flip, which will reverse the triangle winding order (ie, it turns front faces into back faces). You might want to try disabling back-face culling, just to see if it helps.

Comment: @David Thanks for the suggestion. Have checked my vertices order and tried changing CullMode, but, unfortunatelly, that didn't helped.

Comment: @David please check if my "fix" implementation was correct.

Comment: I don't know SharpDX, but that looks correct. If you're still having problems, I suggest using a 3D debugger program. There's a good one here: https://renderdoc.org/builds. It might give you a little more information and help find the problem.